# How to fix "An expression tree cannot contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments" while mocking in C#?

Tags: c#, moq

I have this method which I am try to mock in C# but I am getting an error -

```
Task<(T, HttpStatusCode)> SendPostRequestAsync<T>(
    LoggingContext loggingContext, 
    string path,
    CancellationToken ct, 
    Object requestBody, 
    string spanTitle,
    (IJsonFormatterResolver, IJsonFormatterResolver) formatResolvers, 
    Action<HttpStatusCode> ensureStatusCode,
    Action<HttpRequestMessage> addRequestHeader = null,
    bool disableSpanLogging = false);
```

Here is how I am mocking -

```
_httpClientWrapperMock.Setup(x => x.SendPostRequestAsync<PKKResponse>(
    It.IsAny<LoggingContext>(),
    It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(),
    It.IsAny<PKKRequest>(),
    It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.IsAny<(IJsonFormatterResolver, IJsonFormatterResolver)>(),
    It.IsAny<Action<HttpStatusCode>>(),
    It.IsAny<Action<HttpRequestMessage>>()
)).ReturnsAsync((responseContainer.Response, responseContainer.StatusCode));
```

But I am getting an error as

> An expression tree cannot contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments.

I am not sure what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the value for optional arguments:

```cs
_httpClientWrapperMock.Setup(x => x.SendPostRequestAsync<PKKResponse>(
    It.IsAny<LoggingContext>(),
    It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(),
    It.IsAny<PKKRequest>(),
    It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.IsAny<(IJsonFormatterResolver, IJsonFormatterResolver)>(),
    It.IsAny<Action<HttpStatusCode>>(),
    It.IsAny<Action<HttpRequestMessage>>(),
    It.IsAny<bool>() // or just true/false
)).ReturnsAsync((responseContainer.Response, responseContainer.StatusCode));
```

Currently compiler does not support quite a lot of C# features in [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) (see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4727) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/28481) github issues).

Answer (score 0):

These are not directly related to your issue, but

1. Please try to avoid having parameters like this: `Object requestBody`,
   prefer two generic parameters instead

```
Task<(TResponse, HttpStatusCode)> SendPostAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(
    LoggingContext loggingContext, 
    string path,
    CancellationToken ct, 
    TRequest requestBody, 
    string spanTitle,
    (IJsonFormatterResolver, IJsonFormatterResolver) formatResolvers, 
    Action<HttpStatusCode> ensureStatusCode,
    Action<HttpRequestMessage> addRequestHeader = null,
    bool disableSpanLogging = false);
```

2. Requiring a `CancellationToken` as mandatory parameter feels a bit odd,
   prefer to have it as optional

```
Task<(TResponse, HttpStatusCode)> SendPostAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(
    LoggingContext loggingContext, 
    string path,
    TRequest requestBody, 
    string spanTitle,
    (IJsonFormatterResolver, IJsonFormatterResolver) formatResolvers, 
    Action<HttpStatusCode> ensureStatusCode,
    Action<HttpRequestMessage> addRequestHeader = default,
    CancellationToken ct = default,
    bool disableSpanLogging = false);
```

3. If possible try to prefer more `Uri` class over `string` for urls

```
Task<(TResponse, HttpStatusCode)> SendPostAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(
    LoggingContext loggingContext, 
    Uri path,
    TRequest requestBody, 
    string spanTitle,
    (IJsonFormatterResolver, IJsonFormatterResolver) formatResolvers, 
    Action<HttpStatusCode> ensureStatusCode,
    Action<HttpRequestMessage> addRequestHeader = default,
    CancellationToken ct = default,
    bool disableSpanLogging = false);
```